# Authenticating from a service account. Programmatic IAP authentication fails in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-authentication

I am trying to do programmatic authentication to a different application (project). We have followed the instructions that were listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto). We are using python 3.7 on app engine standard edition.

The default service account (from where the authentication is initiated) has been added to the access list of the application (that is being accessed).

```
response = iap_authentication.make_iap_request(url, client_id)
```

We are stuck with the following error. The make_iap_request class is the code (with no changes) from [here](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#iap_make_request-python). Has anyone had luck making this work? Please help.

```
exception: Bad response from application: 502 / {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Referrer-Policy': 'no-referrer', 'Content-Length': '1613', 'Date': 'Fri, 15 Nov 2019 00:44:06 GMT', 'Alt-Svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000'} / '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=en>\n <meta charset=utf-8>\n <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
\n <title>Error 502 (Server Error)!!
```

Comment: do you an App Engine that is secured with IAP configurations? check [here for more information](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/app-engine-quickstart).

Comment: Yes. We have enabled IAP configurations for this project (application). There is a default service account (from where the authentication is initiated) added as IAP-secured Web App User to this IAP configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue at the moment and there's currently a public issue tracker addressing the problem. Bookmark the link to keep track of the updates. [1]

[1] https://issuetracker.google.com/144749437